# Get string descriptor using PyUSB usb.util.get_string()

Tags: python, windows, pyusb, libusb-1.0

I am having trouble getting the string descriptor of a USB device.  What I'm looking for is the human friendly Manufacturer and Product names.  I am using libusb-1.0 as backend and am able to get the Manufacturer name using the provided libusb test program, so I know it exists.

PyUSB help file says you can access `usb_get_string_simple` (from libusb backend) using:

> get_string(dev, length, index, langid=None)
>
> ```
>    Retrieve a string descriptor from the device.
>    dev is the Device object to which the request will be sent to.
>
>    length is the length of string in number of characters.
>
>    index is the string descriptor index and langid is the Language
>    ID of the descriptor. If langid is omitted, the string descriptor
>    of the first Language ID will be returned.
>
>    The return value is the unicode string present in the descriptor.
> ```

```
import usb
#help(usb.core) 
busses = usb.busses()
for bus in busses:
  devices = bus.devices
  for dev in devices:
    _name = usb.util.get_string(dev.dev,256,0)  #This is where I'm having trouble
    print "device name=",_name
    print "Device:", dev.filename
    print "  Device class:",dev.deviceClass
    print "  Device sub class:",dev.deviceSubClass
    print "  Device protocol:",dev.deviceProtocol
    print "  Max packet size:",dev.maxPacketSize
    print "  idVendor:",hex(dev.idVendor)
    print "  idProduct:",hex(dev.idProduct)
    print "  Device Version:",dev.deviceVersion
    for config in dev.configurations:
      print "  Configuration:", config.value
      print "    Total length:", config.totalLength 
      print "    selfPowered:", config.selfPowered
      print "    remoteWakeup:", config.remoteWakeup
      print "    maxPower:", config.maxPower
      for intf in config.interfaces:
        print "    Interface:",intf[0].interfaceNumber
        for alt in intf:
          print "    Alternate Setting:",alt.alternateSetting
          print "      Interface class:",alt.interfaceClass
          print "      Interface sub class:",alt.interfaceSubClass
          print "      Interface protocol:",alt.interfaceProtocol
          for ep in alt.endpoints:
            print "      Endpoint:",hex(ep.address)
            print "        Type:",ep.type
            print "        Max packet size:",ep.maxPacketSize
            print "        Interval:",ep.interval
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Can you post example output and clarify how it differs from what you'd like?

Comment: Output comes back as: "device name= Љ"
When I use the libusb test application it returns "LG Electronics, Inc"

Answer (score 6):

(**Update July 2019:** See Teodor-Bogdan Barbieru's answer below for a clear description of why you should not actually hardcode indexes!)

(**Second update July 2019:** See gog's comment below for a link to the USB specification containing a table listing all the device descriptor fields.)

The following line in your code:

```
usb.util.get_string(dev.dev,256,0)
```

is indeed the problem. I'm not terribly sure what the USB specification says, but in my current hardware project, I get the following for choices of index:

- index=0 (your choice) returns a single unicode character
- index=1 sends the manufacturer
- index=2 sends the device description
- index=3 sends device serial number

So, try:

```
usb.util.get_string(dev.dev, 256, 2)
```

Good luck!

Comment: NO! Don't hardcode any index. If you are in a hardware project, you should know that you can choose whatever index you want for your String descriptor. The right answer is to use `dev.iProduct` as the index.
Moreover, index 0 will NOT return a single unicode character, but will return the list of supported LANGIDs from the USB device. Please edit your answer, as you are reporting wrong information

Comment: Sure, I'll edit my answer. Seven years ago, I was just describing what I got back from the device I had connected. The PyUSB documentation was not very clear on that point. If you can point me to a better description, I'll add that link to my answer. In the meantime, I'll point to Teodor-Bogdan Barbieru's answer below.

Comment: The PyUSB documentation may not be clear because the USB spec already says it all ;). You can find it [here](https://www.usb.org/document-library/usb-20-specification). Specifically, in the usb_20.pdf file, at Chapter 9.6.1 there's a table that describes all the DEVICE descriptor fields. Chapter 9.6.7 describes STRING descriptors, and the different behavior of STRING descriptor at index 0

Comment: I've updated the answer with a pointer to your comment. Thanks, @gog!

Answer (score 6):

It's not a good idea to hard-code the index.

I would recommend using something like this:

```
usb.util.get_string(dev, 256, dev.iSerialNumber)
usb.util.get_string(dev, 256, dev.iManufacturer)
```

As you will see below the index is different from device to device.

Output of lsusb -v:

```
device 1:            #index #string_descriptor
      iManufacturer  3 Linux 3.8.13 musb-hcd
      iProduct       2 MUSB HDRC host driver
      iSerial        1 musb-hdrc.1.auto

device 2:
      iManufacturer  2 E-boda
      iProduct       3 SUNNY V35
      iSerial        4 0123456789ABCDEF
```

Comment: now the function parameters are a bit different, therefore it does not work with the 256 anymore. It should be:
usb.uti.get_string(dev, dev.iSerialNUmber)

Answer (score 0):

This will retrieve the strings from the device:

```
dev = usb.core.find(idVendor=0x077d, idProduct=0x0410) # fill in your own device, of course
if dev is None:
    print 'Our device is not connected'
else:
    if dev._manufacturer is None:
        dev._manufacturer = usb.util.get_string(dev, dev.iManufacturer)
    print str(dev._manufacturer)
    if dev._product is None:
        dev._product = usb.util.get_string(dev, dev.iProduct)
    print str(dev._product)
```

Comment: This results with an `TypeError: get_string() takes at least 3 arguments (2 given)` because parameter length is not optional.

Answer (score 0):

modify to `usb.util.get_string(dev, dev.iSerialNumber)`

Answer (score 0):

On Windows, `usb.util_get_string(dev, index, lang)` returns an error

```
'array.array' object has no attribute 'tostring'
```

Digging down, in ...lib\site-packages\usb\util.py, line 260, the code says

```
return buf[2:].tostring().decode('utf-16-le')
```

This may work on Linux, but on windows, buf is an array of integers.  It needs to be changed to either a bytearray or a bytes object.  There is no need to convert this to a string - bytes objects can be decoded to utf16

```
return bytes(buf[2:]).decode('utf-16-le')
```

Then everything magically starts working.

Also check the progress of [bytearray addition to array.array](https://github.com/pyusb/pyusb/issues/489).  If this is implemented, this hack may not be required.